# How To Set a list<KeyValuePair<string , string>> in a class using get/set?

Tags: c#, wcf

So I'm currently making a WCF api.
as a result I've created an object and am passing said object to a method.
one of the variables in the object is a `list<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`
Im trying to work out a get/set for setting every item in the list at once. Please Help.

So currently calling a method to set:

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> MailName(List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> fun)
    {
        if(fun != null)
        {
            emailname.Clear();
        }
        int i = 0;

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> thing in fun)
        {
            emailname[i] = fun[i];
            i++;
        }
        return emailname;
    }
```

And a normal list to get:

```
    [DataMember]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> EmailName
    {
        get { return emailname; }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve: in detail please? Currently you seem to be trying to clone the list in the `MailName` method: is that really what you want to do?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That's a different list. You have overlooked I guess.

Comment: Arent you just copying the one list over the top of the other - whats the point of this function when it does seem that if fun is !null, emailname = fun would have done